# How do you make a codeigniter join?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm having trouble creating a join in the codeigniter format, i have a MySQL query that returns what i want:

```
SELECT nwsite.siteid, nwsite.installer_username,
       calcdata.esolar, calcdata.time, calcdata.wsolar
FROM nwsite, calcdata
WHERE nwsite.siteid = calcdata.siteid AND time = '2011-10-29 12:45:00';
```

I've looked at the documentation but i keep getting it wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the CI docs...

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');

$query = $this->db->get();

// Produces: 
// SELECT * FROM blogs
// JOIN comments ON comments.id = blogs.id
```

So in your case, I would not use the cartisian product in your `FROM`, I would actually use a join.

```
$this->db->select("... your fields here...");
$this->db->from("nwsite");
$this->db->join("calcdata", "nwsite.siteid = calcdata.siteid");
$this->db->where("nwsite.time", "2011-10-29 12:45:00");

$query = $this->db->get();
```

For Future reference, I often utilize

```
die($this->db->last_query());
```

to output the actual query that's being generated.  It makes it easier to debug and compare to what you are attempting to generate.

Comment: That should be it, it was the where part i was getting wrong, thanks :)